# After POST request redirect GET method is called but send file is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

When the login button is pressed I send a POST request successfully to my app.js file and just to test try to redirect it with (as instructed) used code 302.
My get request '/' is called and logged 
Exist!
did we work? 
 Why does my sendFile not work as I expected? I am relatively new to this so I may be off base on how to do this. My goal is to after submitting a POST transition the client to a new HTML file

```js
const express = require('express');
const { json } = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
 
app.use(express.json());
 
app.get('/Register', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Register.html');
});

app.get('/Login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Login.html');
});

app.get('/RegisterComplete', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/RegisterComplete.html');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('did we work?')
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Home.html');
});
 
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  res.send({
    username,
    password,
    authorization,
  });
  // fs.readFile('helloworld.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  //   fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', JSON.stringify(req.body) + data, function (err) {
  //       if (err) return console.log(err);
  //     });
  // })
  console.log(req.body + 'i am not what we need');
});

app.post('/Register', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('Logins.Json', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
    const obj = req.body;
    const testObj = JSON.stringify(obj)
    const fileContent = JSON.parse(data)
    const newContent = fileContent['User Info']
    let test = new Boolean(false)
    for (let i = 0; i < newContent.length; i++) {
      if(JSON.stringify(newContent[i]) == testObj){
        //console.log('Exist!')
        test = true
        break
      }
    }
    //console.log(req.body);
    if (test == true) {
      console.log('Exist!')
    }else{
      newContent.push(obj);
      const newData = JSON.stringify(fileContent)
      fs.writeFile('Logins.Json', newData, function (err) {
        console.log('Created Account!')
        if (err) return console.log(err);
      })
    }
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  })
  res.end()
  //console.log(req.body);
});


app.post('/Login', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(302,'/');
  fs.readFile('Logins.Json', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
    const obj = req.body;
    const testObj = JSON.stringify(obj)
    const fileContent = JSON.parse(data)
    const newContent = fileContent['User Info']
    let test = new Boolean(false)
    for (let i = 0; i < newContent.length; i++) {
      if(JSON.stringify(newContent[i]) == testObj){
        //console.log('Exist!')
        test = true
        break
      }
    }
    //console.log(req.body);
    if (test == true) {
      console.log('Exist!')
      //login successful
    }else{
      console.log('Failed')
      // login failed
    }
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  })
});

app.listen(7777, () => {
  console.log('Our express server is up on port 1000');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>eV Login</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="user" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
 
    <script>
        document.querySelector('button')
            .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const username = document
                    .querySelector('#user').value;
 
                const password = document
                    .querySelector('#pass').value;
                     
                fetch('/Login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Vital Gaming',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username,
                        password,
                    }),
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        
                        return res.json();
                    })
                    .then((data) => console.log(data));
            });
    </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: I am anticipating that you want to redirect after the file is been processed. `res.direct(302, '/')` acts as a return statement so the below part is not executed. Try to put it in the end after processing the file systems code.

Comment: @Ishan Joshi - I do believe the file is still processed due to in my log receiving the "Exists" console, but I 100% agree I am just testing the redirect ATM so I placed it at the front of the POST /Login. My GET request from the redirect is being called but the sendFile is not rendering a new HTML file for the client